# SharePoint Online - Token empty error

Tags: sharepoint-online, token

I am creating an app for SharePoint online with provider hosted app model.
I followed all the steps to create an app and ensured both `web.config` and `appmanifest.xml` has same `Client id`.

Though it contains the same `Client id`, while accessing the app I am getting this error:

> token is empty

Please help me, which settings am I missing? The application code is for showing the current user, that's it.

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String contextToken = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Page.Request);
    Response.Write("Token: " + contextToken);
}
```

Web App deployed to Azure web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got the solution to it.
Step 1. In appregnew.aspx page under app domain do not give www. in the url
Util otherwise you have the url. You give without www.
Step 2. Update the new Client id and secret key in azure site

Now run it, will work for sure!

Comment: You can provide redirect URI Redirect with `https or www` for each app registration but for azure websites you don't need to provide `www` =). Glad it worked out!

Comment: Hi Falak, in the reference screen shots, www. can be avoided from Microsoft sites. This was working previously. But now, not.

Answer (score 1):

When developing app aka add-in with Visual Studio 2012/2013, Client ID is being taken care of automatically.

However, at the time of deploying app, [you must register it with both Client ID and Client Secret generated using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860570.aspx) `appregnew.aspx`. App domain is where your web application is being hosted could be Azure/on-prem server.

The `appregnew.aspx` should look like this:[image]

[image]

Once you get the Client ID and Client Secret, you simply register it in app publishing dialog in Visual Studio.

[image]

Upload the *.app package file of the app for SharePoint to the organization app catalog.

Publishing the web application part on Azure before testing app (you must enable https between app and remote web application)

Install the app on site collection and you're good to test the app.

P.S. At the time of publishing the app, Publish Profile (.pubxml) will automatically update the Client ID and Client Secret as a part of deployment in both App and web application project.

Happy SharePointing!

**Updat:**

Check if `https` is used to refer remote application in `Appmanifest.xml?`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Published:70EDFC97-B41D-43C5-B751-7C00AD999804-->
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<App xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest" Name="App" ProductID="{76c0e74b-e6f8-4a3c-883e-aee307ff6a33}" Version="1.0.0.1" SharePointMinVersion="15.0.0.0">
  <Properties>
    <Title>TestApp</Title>
    <StartPage>https://appdomain.lokal/TestApp/?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>        
  </Properties>
  <AppPrincipal>
    <RemoteWebApplication ClientId="SomeGuid" />
  </AppPrincipal>     
</App>
```

Why aren't you using new abstract and concrete classes to develop provider hosted apps? Microsoft is taking care of all nitty gritty and encapsulating the details of ACS (a low-trust app) or S2S apps (a high-trust app). Check out the [Kirk's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/09/24/introducing-sharepointcontext-for-provider-hosted-sharepoint-apps.aspx) for more details

```
  var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);

            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                Response.Write(clientContext.Web.Title);
            }
```

Comment: Once done installing app in catalog, you can install this app in any site collection, as long as the catalog and sites are in the same O365 tenant/SPFarm where you created the Id with appregnew. For publishing app for store, you must get client ID and client secret from there.

Comment: Falak, Thanks for responding! I did all the steps mentioned above. From creating Client Id from appregnew.aspx to publishing. But no luck. The same code works fine, when running in debug mode local.

Comment: It means you're not getting the context token from SharePoint. Something is wrong with app registration. Could you do one more registration using appregnew.aspx? Are you hosting web app part in Azure? Once you publish the app using Visual Studio, check the contents of it appmanifest.xml by renaming .app -> .zip to make sure Client ID matches that of web app.

Comment: Yes, facing issue with Context token. I tried registering new app with client id and secret key. Followed all steps above and deployed. Still the same error.

Comment: Could you paste you code above for getting the context token? Are you publishing in Azure?

Comment: Code, just displaying contextToken. I pasted the code in question section for your reference.

Comment: See my updated response!

Comment: Thanks for the update! I tried that too using the SharePoint context, but no luck. It is very peculiar for me. App creation is not new to me, but from last week when I try to create new hosted app facing this error in all my azure accounts. In appmanifest it is htttps only.

Comment: To test that out, can you create a new app from your side and update me, are you facing the similar issue? Web site is from asia region.